# Angular - executing filter on value change of textboxes

Tags: angular

I'm trying to convert a `ng5-slider` to a min and max textbox for purposes of filtering a list of products by min and max price.

Current Slider:

```
<ng5-slider [(value)]="priceValue" [(highValue)]="highPriceValue" (valueChange)="filterProducts()"></ng5-slider>
```

TS:

```
 filterProducts() {
     this.proposalService.searchFiltereddata = this.proposalService.searchFiltereddata.filter(x => x.monthlyCost >= this.priceValue && this.highPriceValue >= x.monthlyCost);
 }
```

Assuming this slider works as expected with the model and services, how would I set up the 2 textboxes to achieve the same result?
I'm having trouble with whether to use `[value]` or `[ngModel`. Should I be filtering the products on `(ngModelChange)`? What I'm working with so far:

```
<label>Min Price</label>
<input type="text" [value]="priceValue" [ngModel]="priceValue" (ngModelChange)="filterProducts()">

<label>Max Price</label>
<input type="text" [ngModel]="highPriceValue" (ngModelChange)="filterProducts()">
```

Any advice on how to move forward would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One approach would be to use `combineLatest` on the `.valueChanges()` subscription for each text box. You'll get an array of values, one for each subscription, which you can then use to filter your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo Code is** [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kqedef?file=src/index.html)

You can achieve this by using ngModel and ngModelChange bindings in angular as below:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="number" name="priceMinValue" [(ngModel)]="priceMinValue" class="form-control"
                            min="0" [max]="priceHighValue" (ngModelChange)="filterProducts()" placeholder="Min Value">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="number" name="priceHighValue" [(ngModel)]="priceHighValue" class="form-control"
                            [min]="priceMinValue" max="99999" (ngModelChange)="filterProducts()"
                            placeholder="Max Value">
                    </div>
                </div>


filterProducts(): any {
    this.searchFiltereddata
      = this.data.filter(x => x.monthlyCost >= this.priceMinValue && this.priceHighValue >= x.monthlyCost);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!